# Suitable words to describe 'the act of defining parameters' and 'set of parameters' in a software

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Let's say you have a software that does follow up of payments. You define after x days send a reminder email, after y days alert a manager to call that person, after z days alert another department to send legal notice etc. Here x, y, z are called 'parameters'. Please give a single word for the 'set of parameters' and the 'act of defining/setting parameters' in this context.

Comment: 'Set of parameters' and 'defining / setting of parameters'.

Comment: Well, you miss the point. It's about finding **a single word** for 'the act of defining parameters' and **another single word** for 'set of parameters'.

Comment: You miss the point. I'm implying that it's highly improbable there are any.

Comment: It's not easy to imagine a word for these, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: I've answered 'What will you call ...' . I've indicated that I think it's highly likely there aren't single words. I wouldn't have responded to a question starting 'Are there single words to ...'.

Comment: Thanks anyways. You have a _great_ sense of humor, and knack at proving yourself right.

Comment: Config and Configuring - In common use in software maintenance

Answer (score 2):

a) Set of parameters:

> settings

b) Definition of parameters:

> parametrization

Of course a single word can't convey the whole meaning and so will need additional explanation, but afterwards the intended meaning should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions to use the software: To get the desired results from this software, please choose appropriate *parameter **values*** in the first set-up screen.

Critique of the software: Powerful, once you've made it through the *parameter **configuration***.

There are other possibilities.  Please give us a more precise context!  For example, perhaps this is what you want to say: "The first set-up screen is for choosing your ______."  (Guidot's *settings* would work beautifully in such a sentence.)

Comment: “Configuration” is definitely what I would use for “a set of parameters”, and the corresponding verb would be simply “configure”.